# Error : Inputs to Flatten had incompatible triggers: Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()), DefaultTrigger

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While executing the beamSql query I'm getting below error :

```java
Inputs to Flatten had incompatible triggers: Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()), DefaultTrigger
```

My code is :

```java
PCollectionTuple query6 = PCollectionTuple.of(
    new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("record8"), record8).and(new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("record3"), record3);

PCollection<BeamRecord> record9 = query6.apply(
    BeamSql.queryMulti("SELECT a.Vehicle, a.Campaign, a.Copy, a.Event, a.CatLib, a.SubBrand, a.BrandName, a.Channel, a.Period1, a.PeriodStartDate, a.PeriodEndDate, SUM(b.CausalValue) as GRPs FROM record8 a LEFT JOIN record3 b ON a.Channel = b.Outlet AND a.SubBrand = b.SubBrand AND a.Event = b.SalesComponent AND b.Week >= a.PeriodStartDate AND b.Week <= a.PeriodEndDate GROUP BY a.Vehicle,a.Campaign,a.Copy,a.Event,a.CatLib,a.SubBrand,a.BrandName,a.Channel,a.Period1,a.PeriodStartDate,a.PeriodEndDate"));
```

In the document [Apache beam DSL](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/#internals-of-sql) section 3.1, it is written that

> Beam SQL supports aggregation functions with group_by in global_window, fixed_window, sliding_window and session_window. A field with type TIMESTAMP is required to specify fixed_window/sliding_window/session_window.

**Record3:**

```
PCollectionTuple query3 = PCollectionTuple.of(
            new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("record2"), record2).and(new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("apps3"), apps3);        
    PCollection<BeamRecord> record3 = query3.apply(
    BeamSql.queryMulti("SELECT a.Outlet, a.CatLib, a.ProdKey, a.Week, a.SalesComponent, a.DuetoValue, a.PrimaryCausalKey, a.CausalValue, a.ModelIteration, a.Published,  a.CatLibKey, a.SubBrand, a.BrandName, a.FinancialYear, b.EventDescription, b.Vehicle FROM record2 a LEFT JOIN apps3 b ON a.SalesComponent = b.EventList WHERE b.Vehicle IS NOT NULL"));
```

**Record8**

```
PCollectionTuple query5 = PCollectionTuple.of(
            new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("record6"), record6).and(new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("record7"), record7);        
    PCollection<BeamRecord> record8 = query5.apply(BeamSql.queryMulti("SELECT a.Vehicle, a.Campaign, a.Copy, a.Event, a.CatLib, a.SubBrand, a.BrandName, a.Channel, a.Period1, a.PeriodStartDate , b.StartDate as PeriodEndDate FROM record6 a LEFT JOIN record7 b ON a.Period1 = b.FinancialYear"));
```

1. Where in my query shall I implement Repeatedly.forever(...) ?
2. How shall I perform Left Join and Group By in this query ?
3. How shall I implement triggers in this ?

Comment: Note : I'm not using any unbounded source, my input data consist of 1 CSV file stored in Google storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PCollections` you have (`record8` and `record3`) have incompatible triggers. One is `Repeatedly.forever`, while another is `DefaultTrigger`. Which means that Beam cannot reason about what records will be available at which trigger firings, so it cannot produce meaningful JOIN results.

One way to fix this is to set both `PCollections` to `Repeatedly.forever(...)` trigger, see [Setting the triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-a-trigger) section in the Beam guide.

When you have both inputs set to the same trigger, Beam SQL will perform joins and groupbys once per trigger firing.

Version of Beam you are using is likely force-setting the `Repeatedly.forever(...)` when you use the `GROUP BY` clause. This behavior is changed in the upcoming Beam version, `GROUP BY` clause will no longer override the trigger, but it will require both unbounded inputs to have the `DefaultTrigger`.

Comment: Since I'm using Bounded(fixed sized) data source, In this case GlobalWindow should be used. How shall I set GlobalWindow along with Repeatedly.forever(...) in the above query ?